# Making scripts in aframe-react's coding style for A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I find the aframe-react very diferent in comparison with A-Frame-School coding, in concern of scripts especially. I can make all entyties and using  basic components, but what if i want to adapt some script like this?:

```
    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('score-counter', {
          schema: {
            el: {
              type: 'selector'
            },
            score:{
              type: 'int',
              default: 0
            },
          },

          init: function () {
            var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
            var scoreBoard = document.querySelector('#score');

            sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
              this.data.score++;
              var newScore = 'Score: ' + this.data.score
              scoreBoard.setAttribute('text', 'value',  newScore)
            })
          }
        });
        </script>
```

I have this as example for a valid a-frame-react code, but can't find how adapt to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Entity } from 'aframe-react';

import WinLine from './win-line'

const SYMBOL_COUNT = 12;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

class Bonus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    var symbols = [];
    var house = [];
    for (var s = 0; s < SYMBOL_COUNT; ++s) {
      house.push({ s: getRandomInt(0, 3), x: s * 9, k: "sym-" + s });
    }
    symbols.push(house);

    this.state = {
      symbols: symbols
    };
  }

  bonus() {
    setTimeout(() => this.props.main.typeBonusA(), 6500);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.modeI === "in") {
      return (null)
    }
    else if (this.props.clip === "mon") {
      return (

          {this.bonus()}
        </Entity>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <WinLine symbols={this.props.symbols} />
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Bonus
```

...etc (code is cutted)

In previous answer people gives JS code, but i don't know where to put it.

Could anyone tell me how to "port" -code to aframe-react coding style, please? Or the correct way of scripting in aframe-react, or sugestions, any lead will be thanked.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your registerComponent code in its own module.
For example you can place the code in `aframe-helper.js`

```
import AFRAME from 'aframe';
AFRAME.registerComponent('score-counter', {...});
```

and then in your app's entry point just import the module.

```
import 'aframe-helper'
```